# Basic Algorithm Optimization

Tags: c++, collatz

My current assignment is to create a basic algorithm that finds the magic number (which is 1). The magic number can be found by either dividing an even number by 2 until it's magic, or multiplying an odd number by 3, adding 1, the dividing by 2 until 1. We must do this for each positive integer from 3 up until 5 billion.

`MAGIC = 1;`

`DIV = 2;`

`START = 3;`

`MAX = 5000000000;`

```
bool isOdd(int x);
void isMagic(int x);

int main () {

  clock_t startTime = clock();
  cout << "Beginning loop" << endl;

  for (int i = START; i < MAX; i++) 
  {

    if ( isOdd(i) == false ) 
      isMagic(i);
    else if ( isOdd(i) == true )
      isMagic(i);

   }

  clock_t finishTime = clock();
  cout << "Looping took " << double(finishTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;

  return 0;
}


bool isOdd(int x) {

  if( x % DIV == 0 )
    return false;
  else
    return true;

}

void isMagic(int x) {

  if( isOdd(x) == false ) //Is even
  {

    while( x > MAGIC )
    {
        x /= DIV;
    };

  }
  else if( isOdd(x) == true ) //Is odd
  {

    while( x > MAGIC )
    {

      x *= START;
      x += MAGIC;
      x /= DIV;

    };

  }

  return;
}
```

This works, however, it is rather slow. Even with the `-o3` flag in my `makefile` it takes around 115 seconds to complete the task. My professor stated that a decent time would be ~60 seconds. How would I be able to optimize this?

Comment: 115s with what input, on which compiler?

Comment: Requests for feedback on working code should be directed to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your task isn't very clearly stated, however; it would need to be clearly stated for people to understand what you are even doing

Comment: Code `if( isOdd(x) == true )` is odd.

Comment: I do not understand the point of this function at all. It has no observable side effects, so you could simply replace it with an empty function; that would run quickly.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm not entirely sure that this is working code. It seems pretty intuitive that they're supposed to implement the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), and it doesn't appear that they've implemented it correctly.

Comment: This function is not working properly at the first place.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong, you want `while( x > MAGIC )` to be **outside** of the `if`.

Comment: @Justin and with -O3 compiler would completely optimize this function out  and it would take no time, so this is not actual code.

Comment: "create a basic algorithm that finds the magic number (which is 1)" uhmmm.... `return 1` ....

Comment: 1) Why doesn't the compiler optimize-out the entirety of `isMagic`, since it doesn't have any side-effects (no output being printed, no return value, no global variables changing)? 2) Are you sure you understood the assignment correctly? Since the loop in the `else if (isOdd(x) == true) ` case would just keep running until the value stored in `x` overflows, and signed-integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: As said before, looks like Collatz conjecture. Anyway, you also have to take care of possible overflows, for instance with your 5 billion, int of 32 bits is clearly not enough: Log[10^9*5]/Log[2]=32.21 bits

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstood the assignment.
The "either dividing an even number by 2 until it's magic, or multiplying an odd number by 3 and adding 1" should be implemeneted as

```
while( x > 1 )
{
  if( isEven(x) )
  {
    x /= 2;
  }
  else
  {
    x *= 3;
    x += 1;
  }
}
```

Assuming the validity of [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), this can be further optimized as

```
x = 1;
```

Comment: If you fixing code, then fix this `isOdd(x) == false` nonsense

Comment: @Slava: Is it better now??

Comment: yep, much better.

Comment: it seems like the whole sentence is wrongly reproduced. It shouldnt say "either dividing an even number by 2 until it's magic..." but "starting with a number, divide it by two if it is even, do ... when it is odd, until you get the magic number".

Answer (score 0):

Your function runs just once, so if it won't get magic number in one turn it will give you wrong result, also in this case:

```
 while( x > MAGIC )
{

  x *= START;
  x += MAGIC;
  x /= DIV;

};
```

when x is 3 or greater u get an infinite loop, and that's why it runs "slow"
The correct code will be:

```
MAGIC = 1;

DIV = 2;

START = 3;

void isMagic(int x) {
   while (x != MAGIC){
         if(isOdd(x)){
               x *= START;
               x++;
         } else {
               x /= DIV;
         }
   }
}
```

Note that isOdd(x) returns boolean so there is no need in == true

Comment: This is wrong since you divide an odd number by 2 instead of an even number.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the **most** important optimisation you want to implement is not solving the same problem over and over again while checking all numbers from 1 to 5 billion.

Example: when running `isMagic(1742)`, you can run the loop for 179 or so iterations --- or recognize that you have already solved `isMagic(871)` and finish the check at the second iteration.

And when you solve `isMagic(871)`, you shouldn't just record that you have solved 871, you should record **all** the numbers you encounter while solving it, which would be 2614 1307 3922 1961 5884 2942 1471 4414 2207 6622 3311 9934 4967 14902 7451 22354 11177 33532 16766 8383 25150 12575 37726 18863 56590 28295 84886 42443 127330 63665 190996 95498 47749 143248 71624 and so on --- that is, many numbers that are **larger** than the original 871. Finding a way to achieve that is the essence of your assignment.

As a side note, `void isMagic(int x)` is a rather *odd* function signature. Normally a name like `isXYZ(...)` suggests a predicate, that is, a function that returns a boolean. A `void` function with no side effects can be optimised down to `void isMagic(int){}`.